# Get views pager to page by taxonomy term and not content type?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, paging

I have a content type with a taxonomy term with a field. I have a view filtering by the taxonomy term and pager. The view style is set to table with the grouping field set to the taxonomy term. My output is a single taxonomy term with multiple fields.

- taxonomy term
- field
- field
- field

The pager is set to 20 and is displaying 20 fields per page. I would like to display 20 groupings per page by the taxonomy.